# Postgres unable to create postgis extension

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgis, postgres-14

I currently working to install PostgreSQL (v14.4) with the PostGIS (v3.1.4) extension from source using MinGW. I was able to build out all of the dependencies and the build the extension. When I connect to the db, I see that the PostGIS extension is in the `pg_available_extension_versions` table:

```
          name          |  version   | installed | superuser | trusted | relocatable |   schema   |        requires         |                          comment
------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql                | 1.0        | t         | t         | t       | f           | pg_catalog |                         | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis                | 3.1.4      | f         | t         | f       | f           |            |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions
 postgis                | 3.1.4next  | f         | t         | f       | f           |            |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions
 postgis                | unpackaged | f         | t         | f       | f           |            |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 3.1.4      | f         | f         | f       | f           | tiger      | {postgis,fuzzystrmatch} | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 3.1.4next  | f         | f         | f       | f           | tiger      | {postgis,fuzzystrmatch} | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder
 postgis_topology       | 3.1.4      | f         | t         | f       | f           | topology   | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
 postgis_topology       | 3.1.4next  | f         | t         | f       | f           | topology   | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
 postgis_topology       | unpackaged | f         | t         | f       | f           | topology   | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
```

However, when I run, `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/build/pg/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

I went to the exact path that is listed above and the `postgis-3.dll` location is correct. Also, running `ldd` on the `postgis-3.dll` does not show any broken links. Is there something I am missing?